# How do I create build files for my C# application for Mono on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, autoconf

I have written an application called [Abacus](http://stuifzand.eu/abacus/) and released it as free software. Now I need to write build files, so I can build the program from the command line. I currently use MonoDevelop to build the software, but that's not feasible in the long run.

Other projects seem to use `autoconf` and relatives and that's probably the way to go for me too?

Any suggestions where to start? I probably only a small push in the right direction. However Abacus being free software, patches are also greatly appreciated. The code can be found on [GitHub](http://github.com/pstuifzand/Abacus/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoconf` and friends are very common, and probably a good way to go.

However, I believe that MonoDevelop can export a complete build environment (makefiles, etc.) for a project. You may want to investigate that.

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For cross-platform Autotools is a good way to go.

For Mono specific information please see... 
[http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment#Auto-tools](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Deployment#Auto-tools)

For Autotools information in general there's a free book at... http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/